# How to prevent down button in Listbox in C#?

Tags: c#, listbox, keypress, selectedindex

I have a form with a Listbox listing files. I added a KeyPress event with two shortcuts: 'd' (delete), which deletes the file (on disk) and 'k' (keep) which keeps the file (on disk). Both shortcuts remove the selected entry from the list. As a last statement, I added the following in my code to select the first index:

```
if (lstEntries.Items.Count > 0)
{
    lstEntries.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Everything works fine, except when I press 'd', the SelectedIndex changes to 1 instead of 0, which I found very odd. I changed the shortcut to 'r' (for 'remove' instead of 'delete') and now everything works perfectly (the first item gets selected as expected).

Without the Keypress event, I noticed that everytime I press 'd' on my ListBox, it drops down one index. Is this default behaviour? There is nothing in my code to handle a 'd' keypress anymore.

If I set a breakpoint on the selectedindexchanged event, I notice when I press 'd' that the call to change the selectedindex does not originate from within my code, but from the controls, which leads me to believe this is some kind of default behaviour.

So basically: how can I prevent button 'd' from moving the index one down?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check if the handler, or one of the arguments, has something like: `IsHandled` or `CancelEvent` ? if so, put it to `true`. It should stop event propagation in the subscription chain.

Comment: I just found out that if I add e.Handled = true to the KeyPress event, the issue is fixed. But that still leaves me wondering why the 'd' button is the only shortcut for a Listbox?

Comment: @Stefan I missed your comment, I just saw it when I posted my comment. Adding e.Handled = true indeed solved the issue. Thank you!